# Using AZCOPY to copy thousands of copy actions to Azure - Feature not working?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I want to copy thousands of specific blobs and folders from one Azure storage account to another one.

I saw that you can create azcopy jobs. You can handover thousands of copy commands as JSON payload to an azcopy job. The job runs then directly on Azure way faster then executing all those commands locally.
But it seems the creation of those jobs is somehow depricated?
I receive the error that --name is not a proper flag.

I don't find the issue in my code. The documentation from Azure regarding the creation of jobs is poorly done. What am I missing? Is this the proper way?

This is my code:

```
  [...]

# Create an AzCopy job
azcopy jobs create --name $jobName --json $jobDescriptionFile

 #Submit the AzCopy job for execution
azcopy jobs run --name $jobName

azcopy jobs show $jobName
```